# Finding out which drive was booted in x86 bootloader

Tags: x86, interrupt, bootloader, bios, drive

I'm writing a game bootloader for x86.
At one point, early in the booting, I need to load some sectors from my boot drive into memory. I do this with interrupt 0x13 (ah=02), and when I try it in my virtual machine it works like a charm. However when I burn the image to a usb drive, the machine fails to boot, and I pinned it down to the sector loading instructions, apparently my usb drive isn't drive 0 (Floppy A), so the read fails.

How can I determine which drive was used to boot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BIOS loads number of drive bootloader was loaded from to register `dl`. Source: [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/MBR_%28x86%29), section *MBR Bootstrap*.

Comment: Perfect! I guess that's what I get for skipping over these manuals.. Thanks!