# Controller Error (20h) for int 13h for writing a bootloader

Tags: c, assembly, x86, bootloader

I am currently writing a bootloader and can't make any progress.
The job of my bootloader is to load some code (written in C) from an emulated floppy disk and execute it. However the disk read parts, which uses int 13h fails with the error code 20h (Controller failure). I couldn't find any description of what exactly this error means.

I have already looked at numerous tutorials, stack overflow questions and the OS dev wiki and I checked the code for reading from the disk more than 10 times and tried a bit of stuff with changing parameters, but I don't make any progress now.
Perhaps the problem is not the code, but the image itself (which I run with Qemu as a floppy). I create the image, by compiling the actual bootloader code (which works and runs so far, so signature etc. should be correct) and then appending the compiled C code. I check with hexdump and the code is at Address 0x200, right after the signature, so that should be correct. I suspected, that reading one sector exceeds the actual image size, so I am padding the file with zeroes.

Here is the assembler section:

```
// Number of sections
    mov $0x1, %al

    // 0x2 - Read sections
    mov $0x2, %ah

    // Section number (starting from 1)
    mov $0x2, %cl

    // Boot device and head (0)
    mov $0x0, %dx

    // Cylinder
    mov $0x0, %ch

    // Dest Address
    mov $0x7E00, %bx
    mov %bx, %es
    mov $0x0, %bx

    int $0x13
    jc .disk_error
```

Here is how I build and run the image (with make):

```
os.bin: bootloader.bin kernel.bin
    cat bootloader.bin kernel.bin > os.bin
    dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1024 >> os.bin

run: os.bin
    qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=os.bin
```

I can also post the hexdump, if it is useful.

The expected result:
ah is 0, al is 1, carry flag is not set. At address 0x7E00 is the code that I loaded from the floppy.

The actual result:
ah is 20h, carry flag is set. After address 0x7E00 there are only zeroes.

Comment: What happens if you leave the  `%dx` register alone, or only clear `%dh`, instead of setting it to zero?  See these old answers: [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10009565/388520)] [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916738/finding-out-which-drive-was-booted-in-x86-bootloader)]

Comment: I recommend showing your compete bootloader as well as the exact commands (just give us your complete Makefile as well) you use to assemble and link everything to bootloader.bin.

Comment: Leaving dl as it is, results in carry flag set, and ah=1 (Invalid Command).

Comment: It should be noted that you read 1 sector from CHS=(0,0,2) (second sector of disk) to memory address 0x7e00:0x0000 . That is linear address (0x7e00<<4)+0x0000=0x7e000 . Maybe you meant to set ES to 0x0000 and BX to 0x7e00 which is 0x0000:0x7e00 (which is linear address 0x07e00)?

Comment: Because we don't see all your code we also don't know if you set the stack pointer SS:SP to something that you won't accidentally clobber when you read disk sectors into memory. Setting SS:SP to 0x0000:0x7c00 would be okay if you really are intending to read the kernel starting at 0x0000:0x7e00 as the stack would grow down from just below the bootloader while your kernel is being read starting 0x0000:0x7e00

Comment: I'd also hope you are using a `.code16` directive at the top of your bootloader to ensure this is generated as 16-bit code.

Comment: Apart from the good advice of @MichaelPetch, make sure can reset the drive as expected (AH=0). Looking at the source code for seabios (the BIOS used by qemu) I see that it only returns AH=0x20 (DISK_RET_ECONTROLLER) if the actual floppy transaction fails. Are you 100% sure that DL is supposed to be 0x0? IIRC `-drive` mounts a harddisk and I'd ths expect DL to be 0x80. Also make sure interrupts are enabled (even though I think most BIOS enable them as needed...)

Comment: @user786653 : I didn't mention the drive because zwol already brought it up, as his suggestion was to only set DH (the heads) while keeping DL intact. DL will be set (with the boot drive number) by the BIOS before control is transferred by the BIOS to the bootloader. As long as you don't trash DL it can be reused for all the disk routines. You are correct that upon error you should do a drive reset if you encounter an error condition (no need to do one on success) and a general rule of thumb is to retry a disk read/write operation 3 times (if an error) before aborting.

Comment: In the case of reading/writing to disk images there won't be intermittent hardware failures so likely not the cause of the issues here

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yeah, I'm basically just repeating that point, I realize it won't actually do anything on emulated hardware, but the problem can be narrowed down depending on whether that works.

Comment: @user786653 The default is hda is likely the cause of some issues here. Although it is unclear what the OP tried when he took zwol's advice. Alternatively this should boot as floppy drive A as well `-drive format=raw,file=os.bin,index=0,if=floppy`

Comment: Just checked, `-drive` defaults to creating a HD for me. OP is doing something wrong in code we're not shown. My [test code](https://pastebin.com/Y2xugg6y)

Comment: I have now started qemu with the parameters index=0,if=floppy and it works. I read from address 0x7E00 and the content is exactly what I want. Thanks. As a side note, my bootloader is basically assembly embedded in C, so I don't know where the compiled code might be messing with my registers, which is why I prefer to set dx explicitly.